# Private attributes in local class

Tags: java

Is there any use of having private attributes in (private) local class and have get(), set() methods?

```
 class a{
     private class b {
         private int att;
         public int getAtt(){
             return att;
         }
         public setAtt(int att){
             this.att = att;
         }
     }
 }
```

vs

```
  class a{
     private class b {
         public int att;
     }
 }
```

To me it makes sense that all attributes should be public, since they are used only in outer class anyway?

Comment: If you don't need it, don't do it... Especially when the enclosing class `a` is the only user of the class `b`...

Comment: Yes, but it depends on the use of the inner class. Perhaps setting one of the attributes directly could cause inconsistency elsewhere.

Comment: Even if you don't write a setter and a getter, `att` can still be private, since the code of the outer class can access private members of the inner class.

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils Future requirement is really a moot argument since `b` is only used in `a` so they are tightly related anyway... The only valid argument in my opinion is if `b` needs to implement an interface as pointed out in one answer. Anything else falls into the YAGNI category...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess that heavily depends on how you want to use your inner class. If it is only a container for access by the outer class, you can keep the attributes public and avoid getters/setters. Private attributes of the inner class are still useful though for attributes used only by methods in the inner class.

Answer (score 4):

This is a common pattern for factories. The inner private class implements a public interface.

```
public interface IB {

    public int getAtt();

    public void setAtt(int att);

}

static class BFactory {

    public IB makeOne() {
        return new B();
    }

    private class B implements IB {

        private int att;

        public int getAtt() {
            return att;
        }

        public void setAtt(int att) {
            this.att = att;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: More generally if B needs to implement an interface - many examples in the JDK, for example HashMap access Node's attributes directly but there are getters to conform with the `Entry` interface.

Answer (score 1):

it expresses the Encapsulation .
att is be protected in the b,b hide the details that how to set or get att.b only provides the method to external.

Answer (score 0):

Also if the you expose them with getter and setter methods hiding internal representation can be important.

Now `att` is an attribute, but imagine that tomorrow it will be a calculated field. You don't need to change the external class, but only the implementation of setter and getter methods.

Additionally in the setter method you can make a validation of parameter before setting `att`.

Answer (score 0):

It's not necessary to do that with getters and setters, if you want to access the fields in the surrounding class.

If you want to restrict the access from the surrounding class, it obviously makes sense to have getters and setters.